# How do I convert html pages into a single .chm file using PHP?

Tags: php, chm

Is there a library for this task?

Answer (score 3):

Does it have to be PHP? If not, you might have a look at

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Compiled_HTML_Help

Look for "Microsoft Help Workshop." ( http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=00535334-c8a6-452f-9aa0-d597d16580cc&displaylang=en )

A reverse engineering approach is done here: http://www.russotto.net/chm/chmformat.html

So you could look, if you find libraries for the several subproblems.

Answer (score 0):

Check out phpdoc, it can make CHMs

Comment: Afaik not, it generates html to be compiled with MS help workshop.

Which only works on windows.

Answer (score 0):

There is no any direct method for PHP reading/writing CHM file.

This may help. :) http://savannah.nongnu.org/projects/hhm